# Java Procedures + Oracle Database -> NullPointerException

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, nullpointerexception

I don't know but always i try execute my proc to create a product. Return NullPointerException.

So i debug all values and problem happen at line **"cs.execute"**.

## My procedure

This is my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_PRODUTO(
    RESULT OUT int,
    ID OUT PRODUTOS.ID%type,
    NOME IN PRODUTOS.NOME%TYPE,
    VALOR IN PRODUTOS.VALOR%TYPE,
    TIPO_ID IN PRODUTOS.ID_TIPO_PRODUTO%TYPE
  )
IS
BEGIN
  RESULT := 1;
  INSERT INTO PRODUTOS (NOME, VALOR, ID_TIPO_PRODUTO) VALUES (NOME, VALOR, TIPO_ID) returning ID into ID;
  COMMIT;
  EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RESULT := 0;
      ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

## MY TEST IN SQL LITE

If i execute at SQL Commands it works:

```
DECLARE 
  RESULT int;
  ID PRODUTOS.ID%type;
BEGIN

   CREATE_PRODUTO(RESULT, ID, '3', 1, 2);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RESULT || ' ' ||ID);
END;
/
```

That's my java source. My procedure 'll return 2 values ID registred or changed and result if procedure execution success, doesn't.

The code stops at line.

```
cs.execute();
```

## JAVA SOURCE

```
public int save(ProdutoForm form) throws SQLException, ProdutoNaoFoiRegistradoOuAlterado {
    OracleJDBC oracle = OracleJDBC.getInstance();       
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    try{
        Connection c = oracle.getConnection();
        cs = c.prepareCall("{ CREATE_PRODUTO(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }");
        /*
            RESULT OUT int,
            ID OUT PRODUTOS.ID%type,
            NOME IN PRODUTOS.NOME%TYPE,
            VALOR IN PRODUTOS.VALOR%TYPE,
            TIPO_ID IN PRODUTOS.ID_TIPO_PRODUTO%TYPE
        */
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
        cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
        cs.setString(3, form.name);
        cs.setDouble(4, form.price);
        cs.setInt(5, form.type);
        cs.execute();
        if(cs.getInt(1) == 1){  
            return cs.getInt(2);
        } else {
            cs.close();
            throw new ProdutoNaoFoiRegistradoOuAlterado("Produto nao pode ser registrado ou alterado");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        if(cs != null) {
            cs.close();
        }
        throw new ProdutoNaoFoiRegistradoOuAlterado("Produto nao pode ser registrado ou alterado");
    }       
}
```

TRACE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.getNumRows(T4C8Oall.java:917)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1252)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1585)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3929)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4118)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:8721)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:4093)
        at utils.models.ProdutosIterator.save(ProdutosIterator.java:89)
        at controllers.Produtos.save(Produtos.java:67)
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$12$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(routes_routing.scala:230)
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$12$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(routes_routing.scala:230)
        at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(Router.scala:264)
        at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$15$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:255)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:55)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$11.apply(JavaAction.scala:82)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$11.apply(JavaAction.scala:82)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:46)
        at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:492)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$class.apply(JavaAction.scala:82)
        at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$15$$anon$1.apply(Router.scala:252)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:129)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:128)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:128)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:121)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:483)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:483)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:519)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:519)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:496)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:496)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

**Sometime is Exception's message Token SQL92 not supported at position: 3**

Sorry: My source has something in portuguese. Any problem to understand send me a message.

Comment: Well, which line is throwing the exception???

Comment: After that : cs.execute();

Comment: I only commited a mistake. I forgot CALL in the query

Comment: @GuilhermeSoares Adding call did the solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, it resolve issue